# Getting 500 error when trying to create site using SharePoint rest API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint rest API as given in their documentation to create site. We are using client credentials grant flow for authorisation. We are using Global Admin to grant access to our app. It works fine for some tenants but for some tenants its giving 500 error with empty exception message.

Request :

```
Method - Post
url - "http://<site url>/_api/web/webs/add"
headers - 
    "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token
    "content-type" : "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

For some tenants it is creating site properly but for some tenants its giving this error.

```
Status Code: 500
Error: {u'error': {u'message': {u'lang': u'en-US', u'value': u''}, u'code': u'-2146232060, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException'}}
```

So my question is are there any other parameters or permissions for global admin in SharePoint online which are required to create a site as we are using global admin for authorisation?
And since there is empty error message does this error code **"-2146232060"** gives some additional information which can help me in debugging this?

Edit ****
Checking other answers for 500 error which tells to check for updated value of form digest. In this case i am using oauth flow so i am not using form digest.

Comment: What is the POST data that you are sending to the server? Is it always the same and does it meet all the requirements of `WebCreationInformation` object (more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600183.aspx#Anchor_46)

Comment: I am sending this data for WebCreationInformation
'Url': url,
'Title': title,
'Description': description,
'Language': language,
'WebTemplate': webTemplate,
'UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite': True or false.

These parameters are sent for all requests, but may have different values based on site we are creating.

Comment: In that case I would start debugging your issue with checking if the parameters are ok - meaning if the template you are requesting is available for that site, if LCID has been added to site etc. as this might cause the 500 error.

Comment: That's the same thing i thought that there may be problem with one of these values, but I don't have any information about what values are passed. Manually trying to pass wrong value for template or language gives me 500 with specific error message, But in this case i am not getting any message. Can this error code "-2146232060" be of any help? I will debug it more and update if i find something missing.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when you try to create a o365 group(modern sites) under some classic sites eg.Team sites using REST API.